# Is it possible to have both css and scss file names to be the same using Rails Asset Pipeline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5.0.

Is it possible to have both `.css` and `.scss files` be the same name, under the assumption that the `.scss` file gets compiled into the `.css` file?

i.e: This is the file `phones.css` that is trying to compile `phones.scss`

```
/*
 *= require phones #trying to get phones.scss to compile into phones.css
 */
```

Basically, I am trying to have `phones.scss` compiled into `phones.css`. I have tried putting in `phones.css`, besides the `require` keyword, "phones" and "phones.scss" without any success.

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Easier filename readability. I would know just by looking at the filename directory that phones.scss compiles into phones.css. It's not a huge issue, but for a simple project with just one .scss file per .css file, it just seems to me a more logical and intuitive naming system.

Comment: Why don't you just have your file named `phones.scss` and require that in the `application.css` or in whatever view file you need to?

Comment: Just because of the fact that I want to duplicate this file naming structure for a different model (review) and just have have separate stylesheets for different views. i.e: phones.css would go to the phone views, and review.css would go into the review views, and want to keep application.css for site-wide views.

Comment: I understand having different stylesheets for different views quite easily, but not having two files, one with `.css` and another with `.css.scss`

Comment: Well it just seems more intuitive to me atleast that phones.scss gets compiled into phone.css, as they share the same name. Obviously, I could rename it the .scss file something like "phones_scss".scss, but just curious if it would be possible for both to have the same name.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I suspect you're misunderstanding how it works. I may be wrong in that assumption. `phones.scss` can be included in a view with `stylesheet_link_tag` just as a file named `phones.css` and `phones.css.scss`

Comment: Right, that's what I am trying to do. Compile `phones.scss` to `phones.css`  and include `phones.css` in the `stylesheet_link_ tag`. The only trouble I'm having is having phone.scss and phones.css sharing the same name and thus when you add "*=phones" into `phones.css`, it assumes that you're talking about `phones.css`, not` phones.scss`. Not the end of the world if I can't find the solution, but just wanted to know if it was possible as a potential option.

Comment: What I mean is that you do not need to compile `phones.scss` to `phones.css`, the asset pipeline does that for you.

Comment: When you do `*= require phones` in your application.css, the file can be `phones.scss` quite easiliy.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like: `file.css.scss`

Comment: Are you saying I should name phones.css to phone.css.scss, or phone.scss to phones.css.scss?

Comment: Yes. My rails stylesheets have both endings to allow me to use either. Is there a reason you have the .css and .scss in separate files?

Comment: I am asking the question in regards to Rails Asset Pipeline, where .scss files get converted to .css files using the star equals symbol (*= ).  Trying to have an .scss filename that gets converted into a .css with the same filename (i.e: phone.scss and phones.css).